# How to change the google drive menu bar and or google slides from english to spanish

Tags: google-drive-api

I have tried changing the default language in my computer to Spanish as well as preferences in the google slides, however still the menu bar remains in English, does anyone know how to change the menu bar to a language which is not English?

Thanks.-